# QuiltView Library in android

Tags: android

i m developing an android app and i m using the quilt view library i was just wondering how to change the size of the image block and allowing my image to fit the screen edges ie deleting all the margins 
pls if any body could help me

my MainActivity code is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public QuiltView quiltView;

    public ImageView icon1, icon2, icon3, icon4, icon5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        quiltView = (QuiltView)findViewById(R.id.quilt);
        quiltView.setChildPadding(1);

        icon1 = new ImageView(this);
        icon1.setImageResource(R.drawable.agri);
        icon1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);


        icon2 = new ImageView(this);
        icon2.setImageResource(R.drawable.finanace);
        icon2.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        icon3 = new ImageView(this);
        icon3.setImageResource(R.drawable.health);
        icon3.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);


        icon4 = new ImageView(this);
        icon4.setImageResource(R.drawable.travel);
        icon4.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        /*icon5 = new ImageView(this);
        icon5.setImageResource(R.drawable.agriculture);
        icon5.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);*/

        ArrayList<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        images.add(icon1);
        images.add(icon2);
        images.add(icon3);
        images.add(icon4);
        //images.add(icon5);

        quiltView.addPatchImages(images);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you to use AQUery to set Image in QuiltView

```
AQuery aq=new AQuery(this);
ImageView icon4 = new ImageView(this);
            aq.id(icon4).image(R.drawable.travelPic, true, true, 0, 0,
                    null, AQuery.FADE_IN, AQuery.RATIO_PRESERVE);
            icon4.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Incase if you are not comfort with AQuery,  you have to setPadding for each images in QuiltView